# Magento 1.7 overwriting admin phtml file?

Tags: magento

I am trying to overwrite the *app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\head.phtml* template file and so I created a copy of that in my theme folder. That folder is *app\design\adminhtml\default\my_theme\template\page\head.phtml*.

This is not working, but why? Is there no such overwriting mechanism in the admin area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the file, but have you told Magento to use your adminhtml theme?

Magento has documentation for doing this here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's on admin area. go to admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> General Tab -> Design -> on Theme Field, fill your theme name on THEME, SKIN, LAYOUT and DESIGN.

*Don't forget to clear var/cache/* and disabling all Caches in System -> Cache Management*